# Direction of Op Amps Input Bias Current relative to declared sign on datasheet

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, input, bias

Input Bias Current is a parameter of Op Amps related to the Base/Gate currents flowing in or out of the differential amplifiers at the input of the amplifier. It is calculated as the average value of this currents. Ibias=(Ib+ + Ib-)/2. For PNP transistors, Ib+&Ib- are exiting the IC pins. For NPN they are entering the IC pins. So the same pattern should apply to Ibias However, most datasheets won't explicitly say what type of transistors they use on the input. They do declare a sign on Ibias when is negative. Moreover, in some cases, you find Ibias values that do not have any sign (either negative of positive) and they could be either PNP or NPN transistors. For example, LM741 has NPN transistors (just google LM741 internal circuit) and its datasheet says "Input bias current: 80 nA"; while the LM311 datasheet says in pag. 11 "LMx11 consists of a PNP input stage to sense voltages near VCC" and "Input bias current: 100 nA".

So, the question: Does any body know if there is an agreement or standard on this Ibias sign declaration?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Does any body know if there is an agreement or standard on this Ibias sign declaration?

If the quiescent current or the output sink current, which are both entering currents, is given as positive (or without any sign) then any current with a (–) sign should indicate an exiting current (e.g. output source current). That's the only thing.

> For PNP transistors, Ib+&Ib- are exiting the IC pins. For NPN they are entering the IC pins. So the same pattern should apply to Ibias

No. There's not a direct relation between having PNP or NPN input stage and the input bias current direction. The base current of a PNP flows "out" of the base pin but this doesn't have to be the input bias current that the datasheets refer to. Some op amp designs may have input bias cancellation inside, some don't. So the input bias current can be in any direction. There are some op amps having input bias currents specified with ± sign which means "both directions". LT5115 and OPA1655 are some examples. OPA207, which clearly has an NPN input stage (at least this is what the datasheet shows), has its input bias current given as ±1 nA.

Comment: Another piece that confirms the "positive-in, negative-out" convention is this: MOSFET opamps don't have notable input bias current through the gate, so they don't use bias current cancellation. For more positive input voltage, the inputs *sink* current through the low ESD diodes and for negative input voltage, the current sourced from the top diode dominates. And indeed, datasheets display the bias current as more positive (more "in"-going) at higher input voltages.

Comment: Great replay! Thanks guys.

Comment: @RicardoM. You can accept the answer (by clicking the tick under the points counter) so that the question does not remain open. Because open questions are always being "poked" at random times.